# buttons shifts below when the heading tag is large

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile site and I have a code like below.

```
<div class="profile-div-wrapper">
   <div class="profile-div">
    <div class="header">
     <img src="assets/images/image.png" alt=""><h3 id="txtDisplayUserName">Surajjjjjjjjjjj Shukla</h3>
     <a href="update_user_profile.html" class="bttn3">Edit Profile</a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the heading is bigger, anchor Edit Profile shifts below.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/7sxxf6pg/1/) the fiddle for the same. What can be done to solve this?

Note: Please make sure you make the fiddle of mobile device size to see the problem..

Comment: Set a `max-width` on the heading tag and clip it once the content within exceeds that width, You could use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` if you prefer to clip it with an ellipsis "..."

Comment: didn't get you @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: See here @Suraj : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow (might steer you in the right direction)

Comment: I got 'text-overflow: ellipsis;' but unable to implement the same on my code...

Comment: Post a code snippet of what you have so far. `text-overflow: ellipsis` is dependent on a few complimenting styles, like a explicitly set `width` or `max-width`, `overflow: hidden`, and `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

Try adding this to your existing code:

```
.profile-div .header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.profile-div .header a.bttn3 {
  margin-left: auto; //instead of float: right;
  display: flex; //instead of display: block;
  //to vertically & horizontaly align the text inside the button
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3Lfprw6/2/

Comment: when the heading is bigger, the buttons gets shorten, I mean I can only see Edit then

Comment: @SurajShukla Try and check the jsfiddle in the edit.

Comment: @SurajShukla if you want the button to stay with a fixed width add a `min-width: 115px`

Comment: If you notice your fiddle, the buttons style got changed from how It looks on mine

Comment: Now It affects the image which I have. It gets distorted for some reason...